# Is there an 'invisible' argument for setFill() from graphics.py? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, invisible

I've recently downloaded the graphics.py package for Python 2.7 and I have just been playing around with it. I have created a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes (non-blue squares indicate prime numbers). Here is the code:

```
def grid():
win = GraphWin("grid",300,300)
p=0
for i in range(0,191,20):
    for j in range(0,191,20):
        p=p+1
        t = Rectangle(Point(j,i),Point(j+20,i+20))
        e.draw(win)
        t.draw(win)
        for n in range(2,p):
            if p%n==0:
                t.setFill('blue')
grid()
```

I wanted to label each square with a number, so I have been trying to use 'Entry'. I've used the following commands to get a grid of numbers:

```
e = Entry(Point(j+10,i+10),3)
e.getAnchor()
e.setText(p)
e.getText()
e.setSize(8)
```

But the background colour (default grey) overlaps my blue/non-blue squares so that my original grid is not visible and all I can see is my array of numbers. I can change the background colour with setFill('blue') (for example) but I was wondering if there is any argument such as 'clear' or something similar which makes the background invisible to reveal my grid underneath. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I know I can just change the background colour of the entry boxes to display the prime/non-prime information by changing t.setFill('blue') to e.setFill('blue') but it would be useful to be able to get a clear background for other projects.